# ng-repeat causing additional rows in list when adding icons to it

Tags: angularjs

I have a list that displays documents tied to a case number. I am displaying them as follows:

```
<ul class="doc-list">
                    <li ng-repeat="docs in casedocs">
                        <a ng-href="#" ng-click=loadDocument(docs.Doc_Path)>{{docs.Description}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

This works just fine. However, if I add anything in front of the  list item I get many empty rows added to the list. For instance, if I change the code to be:

```
<ul class="doc-list">
                    <li ng-repeat="docs in casedocs">
                        X <a ng-href="#" ng-click=loadDocument(docs.Doc_Path)>{{docs.Description}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

there are a bunch of extra empty rows in the list. What can I do to stop this behavior? See the two images to show what it looks like correct and what it looks like when wrong:

[image: Correct listing]
[image: Incorrect listing]

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like? Is it creating extra list items (1 for each "X"), or is it somehow just duplicating the "X" as text nodes, etc.). I would expect the ng-repeat to only show 2 list items, but the picture makes it look like there are 8 list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this answer in case someone else has this issue. The service was apparently returning null records that were filtered by both the browser when looking what the service returned and Postman as well. We fixed the service to not return those null records and the problem resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code, it worked fine (in Chrome and FF at least), no additional/empty rows were created after addition of arbitrary characters in front of the link. Whatever the problem is it doesn't seem to be Angular's fault. Anyway, here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul class="doc-list">
      <li ng-repeat="docs in casedocs">
          Xasdf <a href="#" ng-click="loadDocument(docs.Doc_Path)">{{docs.description}}</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
  $scope.casedocs = [
    {
      description:"One", 
      Doc_Path:"someUrl"
    },
    {
      description:"Two", 
      Doc_Path:"someUrl"
    },
    {
      description:"Three", 
      Doc_Path:"someUrl"
    }
  ];
  $scope.loadDocument = function(url){
    alert(url);
  }
}]);
```